# Eigen OLS vs python statsmodel.api.OLS

Tags: python, c++, linear-regression, eigen, statsmodels

I need to calculate the slope,intercept of the line for a regression between 2 vectors with data. So i made a prototype with python below code:

```
A = [1,2,5,7,14,17,19]
b = [2,14,6,7,13,27,29]

A = sm.add_constant(A)
results = sm.OLS(A, b).fit()

print("results: ", results.params)
```

> output: [0.04841897 0.64278656]

Now I need to replicate this using `Eigen` lib in `C++` and as I understood, I need to pass a `1` column in the matrix of `A`. If I do so, I get totally different results for the regression than if I just use no second column or a `0` column. `C++` code below:

```
Eigen::VectorXd A(7);
Eigen::VectorXd b(7);

A << 1,2,5,7,14,17,19;
b << 2,14,6,7,13,27,29;

MatrixXd new_A(A.rows(), 2);
VectorXd d = VectorXd::Constant(A.rows(), 1);
new_A << A, d;

Eigen::MatrixXd res = new_A.bdcSvd(Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV).solve(b);

cout << " slope: " << res.coeff(0, 0) << " intercept: " << res.coeff(1, 0) << endl;
cout << "dbl check: " << (new_A.transpose() * new_A).ldlt().solve(new_A.transpose() * b) << endl;
```

> output with '1' column added to new_A ->  slope: 1.21644 intercept:
> 2.70444 output with '0' or no column added -> slope: 0.642787 intercept: 0

How to get same results in `C++`? Which one is the right one, I seem to trust more the python one since I get the same when I use 0 column.

thank you,

Merlin

Answer (score 1):

It seems i had to invert new_A with b, and replace ComputeThin with ComputeFull so that it builds.

```
Eigen::MatrixXd res = b.bdcSvd(Eigen::ComputeFullU | Eigen::ComputeFullV).solve(new_A);
```